# Append HTML As String With Input validators

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to append input fields with validator with type `required` and `message`.
I append html elements as `string` like this. What can you recommend me ?

```
content += '<td><input class="cars" type="text" name="amount" CompanyID=' + companyID + '></td>';
```

Comment: Recommend about what?

Comment: First, escape `companyId` for quotes, ampersands and backslashes; second, use HTML5 compatible attributes, for example `data-company-id`; third, try to figure out if it's better to set the attribute on the DOM rather than the HTML content.

Comment: I can recommend that you clarify this question?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `required` attribute?

```
content += '<td><input required class="cars" type="text" name="amount" CompanyID=' + companyID + '></td>';
```